# How do I make a slideshow with fade-out effects?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I attempted to make the background be a slideshow with javascript, but it's not working properly. Except for the first time the image changes after I hit refresh, everything works perfect. However, the first time the image fades out, it glitches out, and the first image that fades away reappears for a split second and then disappears again. How do I fix this? Here is the code:

```
//javascript file for the index page

//Create the slide show for the background
var backgroundImgS = "images/background1.JPG", backgroundImg2S = 
"images/background2.JPG", backgroundImg3S = "images/background3.JPG";

var backgroundImg = document.getElementById("backgroundImg"), backgroundImg2 
= document.getElementById("backgroundImg2");

/*If the background slide show isn't transitioning, transNum increments 
every cycle. When transNum gets to a certain number, trans becomes true as 
the slide show starts to transition.
transNum is in that case returned to 0, and opacity goes down 10 per cycle 
(opacity is the opacity of backgroundImg). When opacity is at 0, 
backgroundImg is assigned the src of
backgroundImg2, and backgroundImg's opacity is returned to 100. After that, 
backgroundImg2's src is changed the the next image. imgNum determines which 
image the main background
image should contain.*/

var transNum = 0, opacity = 100, trans = false, imgNum = 1;

window.setInterval(function(){
//background slideshow
if(!trans) transNum++;//if the slide show isn't transitioning, increment transNum
if(transNum == 100){//if transNum has counted to 80, start the transition of the background image
    transNum = 0;
    trans = true;
}

if(trans) opacity -= 10;//make the first image less transparent
if(opacity == 0){
    trans = false;
    if(imgNum > 2) imgNum = 0;

    if(imgNum == 0){
        backgroundImg.src = backgroundImgS;
        backgroundImg2.src = backgroundImg2S;
    } else if(imgNum == 1){
        backgroundImg.src = backgroundImg2S;
        backgroundImg2.src = backgroundImg3S;
    } else if(imgNum == 2){
        backgroundImg.src = backgroundImg3S;
        backgroundImg2.src = backgroundImgS;
    }

    opacity = 100;
    imgNum++;
}

backgroundImg.style.opacity = opacity / 100 + "";
backgroundImg.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity + ")";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make slide to auto play and change swap to fade in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983414/how-make-slide-to-auto-play-and-change-swap-to-fade-in-javascript)

Comment: you shouldn't create effects with JavaScript when you can do it with `animation` css.
and this type of image loading approach is not good when you add or remove images in the future. it just makes the code hard to maintain.
The glitch you mentioned here it may caused by image loading, you need to start your slider after all images loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this will fix everything, but you should probably be making use of the image `onload` event handler to make sure your images -- which load asynchronously -- have been fully loaded and rendered before you apply effects to them.